# Getting iterations of a loop to output on same line

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I need to take a series of text inputs, and combine them with a number and some formatting. The catch is that I don't know how many elements the series of inputs will have beforehand. I know this would be easy to do for a set number of inputs, but I need a function that will iterate as many as necessary.

So basically I need to take 'apple banana cherry ...' and '5'
and output:

```
str('{"apple": 5, "banana": 5, "cherry": 5, "...": 5}')
```

This is what I have so far:

```
print("Enter fruits:")
fruits = [x for x in input().split()]
print("Enter Maximum Fruits per Day")
maxfruit = input()
def maxfruitfuncstep1(x,y):
    return str('"' + x + '"' + ": " + y)
for i in fruits: 
    print("{" + maxfruitfuncstep1(i,maxfruit) + "}")
```

but that just gives me output:

```
{"apple": 5}
{"banana": 5}
{"cherry": 5}
```

How can I get the function to run horizontally within the printout? I've tried using ",".join but that just gave me:

```
",a,p,p,l,e,",:, ,5
```

Comment: Not sure, what exactly your question here is. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493386/8881141)?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
maxfruit ="5"
print("{" + ", ".join(fruit + ": " + maxfruit for fruit in fruits) + "}")
```

Another solution is simply:

```
repr({fruit: maxfruit for fruit in fruits})
```

Comment: upvoting yours, better than mine :D

Comment: is using "for listname in listname" the key? I feel like it wasn't letting me do "for i in listname" in the middle of the line

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

One way is something like:

```
fruits = ['banana', 'strawberry', 'cherry']

max_num = 5

from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(dict)

for x in fruits:
    result[x] = max_num

str(dict(result))

"{'banana': 5, 'strawberry': 5, 'cherry': 5}"
```